# How do I access JSON elements Dynamically through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My Json file is:

```
    {
  "root": {
    "Quizsize": null,
    "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}page": [
      {"{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}nut": {
              "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}uttering": {
                "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}info": null,
                "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}utterance": {
                  "@lang": "fr",
                  "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}ezread": {
                    "@text": "",
                    "@lang": "fr",
                    "@kind": "standard",
                    "@type": "ezread"
                  },
                  "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}translation": {
                    "@text": "How much does it cost?",
                    "@lang": "en",
                    "@kind": "standard",
                    "@type": "translation"
                  },
                  "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}native": {
                    "@text": "",
                    "@lang": "fr",
                    "@kind": "standard",
                    "@type": "native"
                  },
                  "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}phonetic": {
                    "@text": "",
                    "@lang": "fr",
                    "@kind": "standard",
                    "@type": "phonetic"
                  },
                  "@anchor": "native"
                }
              }
            }
            ]

      }
    }

}
```

I need to access the @text property depending upon the value in @anchor property :

so my steps to access are:
1.load this JSON in lesson variable.
2. Get root element  (lessonPages = lesson.root)
3.Now access @anchor property value through below code:
**text = lessonPages["{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}"]["{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}nut"]["{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/page}uttering"]["{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}utterance"]["@anchor"]**

Now i have @anchor value in text variable which is "native".Now how can i use text variable value to access @text in "{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}native"

Note:@anchor property value is not fix.It could be anything,so we need to first read it and then @text depending upon that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a string. You can concatenate strings as normal.

```
foo["{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}" + someStringVariable]
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin,this works for me.I have 1 more problem, can i create full request path using strings and access properties.Suppose if i have: var a = 'foo["{urn:abc.com/xmlns/mona/utterance}" '+ someStringVariable']' .This variable a contains string, can i use this string to further access JSON element?